# Step Progress Bar - Alternate <li> text top and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to build a progressbar by using a `li` element.

```
  <div class="stepprogresscontainer" id="stepprogressbar">
<div class="frontdiv" style="display: block; z-index: 5; position: relative;">
  <ul class="stepprogressbar">                 
    <li id="li-s-1" class="activeli">Schaden angelegt</li>
    <li id="li-s-2" onclick="activeli2()">xxxx1</li>
    <li id="li-s-3" onclick="activeli3()">xxxx1</li>
    <li id="li-s-4" onclick="activeli4()">xxxx1</li>
    <li id="li-s-5" onclick="activeli5()">xxxx1</li>
    <li id="li-s-6" onclick="activeli6()">xxxx1</li>
    <li id="li-s-7" onclick="activeli7()">xxxx1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="position:relative; top: 20px;"  class="behinddiv">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36); height: 3px; display: block; margin-left: 8%; margin-right: 8%;"></div>
  <div id="coverline" style="transition: width 1s ease; background-color: #2ac570; height: 3px; display: block; margin-left: 8%; margin-right: 8%; margin-top:-3px; width: 0%;"></div>
  <div id="progressline" style="background-color: #2ac570; height: 3px; display: block; margin-left: 8%; margin-right: 8%; margin-top:-3px; width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stepprogresscontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.stepprogressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 14%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(187, 68, 68);
  font-family: witneyfont;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.stepprogressbar li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border: 1.5px solid rgb(187, 68, 68);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am trying to achieve now that every other `li` element text is on top of the :before pseudo element. Right now everything is below the before element. I need to alter between so the text doesnt overlap on window resize.

currentlty it looks like that:
[image]

i need something like that:
[image]

Is there any easy way I didn't consider yet?

Thanks!

Comment: I know how to select the elements with li:nth-child. I am just not able to to position the li text part on top of the pseudo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put title on each elements `:before` and `:after` with `content: attr(attribute-name)`. Then on even elements hide `:after`, on odd elements hide `:before`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 6;
}

ul li:before,
ul li:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

ul li:before {
  top: -15px;
}

ul li:after {
  bottom: -15px;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd):before {
  display: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(even):after {
  display: none;
}

ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-text="xxx1"></li>
  <li data-text="xxx2"></li>
  <li data-text="xxx3"></li>
  <li data-text="xxx4"></li>
  <li data-text="xxx5"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but you got me the idea to find the solution. thx.